# NPOI - HSSF Date Format from row 10 in EXCEL 2013

Tags: npoi, poi-hssf

I'm using the NPOI 2.0 Version of this library, and I'm having an issue when creating an Excel file and try to open with Microsoft Excel 2013.

There is a column with date format, that works fine from row 1 to 10, but from row 11 the program stops reading this property and shows a weird decimal value.

The library works perfect for me in older versions of Excel, OpenOffice and GoogleDrive.

Comment: Think we need to see some code where you write the file data